# Can Etcher be used to customize the base Raspbian image?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, operating-systems, pi-a

I was wondering if anyone in this community has used [Etcher](https://etcher.io/) to burn OS images to a Raspberry Pi. I have a Rapberry Pi 1 Model A and would like to use Etcher to burn [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) to it with some custom modifications:

- I want to start with Raspbian Stretch Lite as the base image
- Then I have several *nix packages that I'd like to add to that image using something like `apt-get`
- Then I want to install my own app/service at a particular location on the file system
- Finally I want the whole OS configuration/image to be burned onto the pi so that when I power it on, Raspbian starts running and its just like I had manually provisioned the server myself

Can Etcher accomplish all this for me? Or do I need to load the Raspbian image into a different tool and customize it (run `apt-get`, manually install my app, etc.) from there? What would that tool pipeline look like? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No , Etcher alone cannot accomplish this. The following will , though (listed in ascending order of complexity/flexibility) :

- [PiBakery](http://www.pibakery.org)
- [pi-gen](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen)
- [chroot + qemu-user-static](http://sentryytech.blogspot.com/2013/02/faster-compiling-on-emulated-raspberry.html)

The last option only works on Linux but will enable you to "jump into" an image file , use apt-get , change configuration files etc.

Comment: I'm new to this SE, but isn't there community guidelines to summarize solutions in case of link rot? `rpi-gen` is already a lost cause.

Comment: No you can't do that using Etcher as it only writes the ISO. You could add files to the ISO maybe, using a compressed file viewer. PiBakery is what you need. Take a standard image (included) and add items like first boot scripts, WiFi networks and Cron jobs.